# Error "Maximum processes allocated for plug-in business logic exceeded" in Microsoft Dynamics 365 v9.1 OnPremise

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are seeing the error below in Microsoft Dynamics 365 v9.1 OnPremise, this happens since we upgraded to V9.1, we've never seen this issue before (full stack trace below)

This happens intermittently and we can't pin down what action causes it. When this happens, the dynamics API fails with the error for about 5 minutes before it recovers itself.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue?

```log4j
[2022-02-15 08:25:16.613] Process: w3wp |Organization:402bf48d-1f8e-eb11-9124-005056010f8a |Thread:   23 |Category: Platform |User: e8012d0a-c65a-e911-a2d1-0cc47a688a65 |Level: Error |ReqId: c3cede64-cbf2-4eda-8338-d4ffe7239951 |ActivityId: a6ee5d32-080e-481f-be64-3f3b0ed53d99 | MessageProcessor.Execute  ilOffset = 0x47A
>MessageProcessor fail to process message 'RetrieveMultiple' for 'contact'. Error:
>Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Maximum processes allocated for plug-in business logic exceeded. Fatal errors in plug-ins for this environment have occurred 20 times in the last 5 minutes. Each error requires an additional process to recover. Processes for plug-ins are being recycled. All plug-ins for this environment will fail during this period. More information: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2038718 
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.ProcessException(Exception originalException, IExecutionContext context, SandboxClient client, SandboxCallTracker callTracker, Boolean isSafeToRetry, DateTime performanceExecutionStartTime, SandboxTracker tracker, Guid parentExecutionId, CrmException& crmException, String& assemblyContents)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<Execute>b__0()
>   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
>   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
>   at Microsoft.Xrm.RemotePlugin.CrmProvider.RemotePlugin.CDSExecute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PipelineInstrumentationHelper.Execute(Boolean instrumentationEnabled, String stopwatchName, ExecuteWithInstrumentation action, PipelineExecutionContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<RunStep>b__0()
>   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
>   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PipelineInstrumentationHelper.Execute(Boolean instrumentationEnabled, String stopwatchName, ExecuteWithInstrumentation action, PipelineExecutionContext context)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context) Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Maximum processes allocated for plug-in business logic exceeded. Fatal errors in plug-ins for this environment have occurred 20 times in the last 5 minutes. Each error requires an additional process to recover. Processes for plug-ins are being recycled. All plug-ins for this environment will fail during this period. More information: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2038718 
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.ProcessException(Exception originalException, IExecutionContext context, SandboxClient client, SandboxCallTracker callTracker, Boolean isSafeToRetry, DateTime performanceExecutionStartTime, SandboxTracker tracker, Guid parentExecutionId, CrmException& crmException, String& assemblyContents) +0x0
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<Execute>b__0() +0x25e
>   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties) +0x90
>   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action) +0x13
>   at Microsoft.Xrm.RemotePlugin.CrmProvider.RemotePlugin.CDSExecute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) +0x223
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context) +0x399
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context) +0x1ff
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PipelineInstrumentationHelper.Execute(Boolean instrumentationEnabled, String stopwatchName, ExecuteWithInstrumentation action, PipelineExecutionContext context) +0x83
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<RunStep>b__0() +0x16f
>   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties) +0x90
>   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action) +0x13
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context) +0x106
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PipelineInstrumentationHelper.Execute(Boolean instrumentationEnabled, String stopwatchName, ExecuteWithInstrumentation action, PipelineExecutionContext context) +0x83
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context) +0x47a
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, a plug-in is failing repeatedly and faster than can be restarted.

I recommend to look at XrmToolBox's [PluginTraceViewer](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Cinteros.XrmToolBox.PluginTraceViewer/) to investigate the cause of exceptions.

Comment: thanks, I’ll give this a try. The issue is intermittent and other people seem to have it too since v9.1, I raised it in the CRM forum too https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/448316/error-maximum-processes-allocated-for-plug-in-business-logic-exceeded-in-microsoft-dynamics-365-v9-1-onpremise/1229264